# using STL with Alchemy

Tags: flash, alchemy

While Alchemy supports compiling C++, it seems that using the using the STL is trouble, mostly due to a [problem with std::string](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/487570).  What's strange is that Alchemy seems to be using [GNU libstd++ v3.4.6](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/pub/gnu/gcc/gcc-3.4.6/).  It's hard to believe that std::string is broken in GNU's STL.

Has anyone figured out any workarounds for this problem?  C++ without the STL is like a fish without water.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't in the STL as such.  The GNU implementation of `std::string` is reference-counted using the thread-safe functions `__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add` and `__gnu_cxx::__atomic_add`.  The problem is that `__exchange_and_add`/`__atomic_add` are broken.

The solution is to rebuild the STL with good implementations of these functions.

Fortunately, the Alchemy distro leaves some breadcrumbs for us.  See `$ALCHEMY_HOME/avm2-libc/README`, which tells us how to do it:

```
The sources used to build avm2-libstdc++.l.bc can be downloaded here:
  http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/alchemy/alchemy_gnucpp3-4library_121008.zip

To build avm2-libstdc++.l.bc:
 cd $ALCHEMY_HOME/avm2-libc
 unzip alchemy_gnucpp3-4library_121008.zip
 mv lib/avm2-libstdc++.l.bc lib/avm2-libstdc++.l.bc.OLD
 make 

You should *not* run achacks prior to using these building this library with make.
The Makefiles provided have been preconfigured to use LLVM directly where needed.
```

Normally I'd expect to find the implementations of __exchange_and_add/__atomic_add in libstd++ (`$ALCHEMY_HOME/avm2-libc/lib/avm2-libstdc++.l.bc`), but for some reason they're defined in libc (`$ALCHEMY_HOME/avm2-libc/lib/avm2-libc.l.bc`).

I'm not sure why this is the case, but we can work around it by hacking atomicity.h, where the prototypes are kept.  Note that after unpacking alchemy_gnucpp3-4library_121008.zip, you'll need to edit *two* atomicity.h files:

- `$ALCHEMY_HOME/avm2-libc/include/c++/3.4/bits/atomicity.h`
- `$ALCHEMY_HOME/avm2-libc/libstdc++/include/bits/atomicity.h`

Here is the code:

```
  /*
   * __exchange_and_add and __atomic_add are broken in Alchemy's libc.
   * Replace them with functioning implementations.  This isn't
   * cross-platform, but this codebase is only compiling for Alchemy anyway.
   */
  #define __exchange_and_add(x,y) __exchange_and_add_fix((x),(y))
  #define __atomic_add(x,y) __exchange_and_add_fix((x),(y))

  /*
   * Correctly implement __exchange_and_add.  It's not thread-safe,
   * but Alchemy isn't threaded, so we should be ok.
   */
  inline _Atomic_word __exchange_and_add_fix(volatile _Atomic_word* __mem, int __val) {
     int orig= *__mem;
     (*__mem)+= __val;
     return orig;
  }
```

Here is some test code to run to make sure the rebuilt STL works:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void string_test() {
    string s1;
    string s2;

    s1 = "a";
    s2 = s1; // copy constructor
    s1 = "b";

    // use your favorite TRACE function here
    printf("s1= %s \n", s1.c_str()); // expected: "b", actual: "b"
    printf("s2= %s \n", s2.c_str()); // expected: "a", actual: "b", ERROR
}

void map_test() {
    map<string, int> test_map;

    test_map["test1"]= 1;    
    test_map["test2"]= 2;
    test_map["test3"]= 3;    

    string tmp= "test1";
    printf("%s : %d \n", tmp.c_str(), test_map[tmp]);
}

void ifstream_test()
{
    std::ifstream in("test.txt");

    // ERROR 1:
    // Trying to seek file throws an error:
    // Error #1006: value is not a function.
    // at: basic_filebuf::char_traits::seekoff
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int length = in.tellg();
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    printf("File Length: %d \n", length);

    while(in.good()) {
        char buffer[512];

        // ERROR 2:
        // RangeError: Error #1125: The index 1092156 is out of range 721.
        // at basic_filebuf::char_traits::underflow::work()
        in.getline(buffer, 512, '\n');

        printf("buffer= %s \n", buffer);
    }
}

int main() {
    string_test();
    map_test();
    ifstream_test();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the rebuilt STL appears to fix some related issues with [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756250/stdmap-broken-in-alchemy) and [ifstream](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/487828).

Comment: This problem was the reason I abandoned Alchemy.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Gunslinger47: If you're up for rebuilding the STL, it seems like you might be able to start using Alchemy again.  Assuming you didn't move on to some other technology. :)