# Using opencv in Flash Alchemy

Tags: flash, opencv, alchemy

I have a project that uses quite a few opencv libs to do some image processing tasks.  Now I need to build a Flash app for it.  I read that Alchemy allows compiling c++ libs for Flash.  I wonder if anyone has tried to build flash apps using opencv libs and dlls?  Thanks.

Comment: There is a project on github about this: [https://github.com/bonext/flash-opencv](https://github.com/bonext/flash-opencv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile C++ libs, but [watch out for std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421832/using-stl-with-alchemy).  Also, you won't be able to use DLLs-- everything has to be statically compiled into one SWC.

Comment: can you please provide some pointers about how to do this?  I searched the web but couldn't find much on this topic.  Thanks.